# How to pass variable in s3api to filter the object using lastmodified?

Tags: amazon-s3

I was trying to filter the S3 objects based on lastmodified using below command -

Upon providing the date manually like this `LastModified>=2018-12-20` in `--query` it worked fine.

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket $bucketNameToUse --query 'Contents[?LastModified>=`2018-12-20`].{Key: Key, LastModified: LastModified}' --output text
```

But when I tried to use Date variable in place of `2018-12-20` like below -

```
echo $DATEVARIABLE
2018-12-20

aws s3api list-objects --bucket $bucketNameToUse --query 'Contents[?LastModified > `$(DATEVARIABLE)`].{Key: Key, LastModified: LastModified}' --output text
```

It print every object in the bucket, I tried all possible way to use bash variable but didn't work. Not sure what I am missing here. Any Suggestion please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS CLI uses [JMESPath](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-output.html) for --query option. Following worked for me after passing query in double quotes as a string.

```
--query "Contents[?LastModified>='${DATEVARIABLE}'].[Key, LastModified]"
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution with backtick (`) -

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket $bucketNameToUse --query 'Contents[?LastModified > `'$DATEVARIABLE'`].{Key: Key, LastModified: LastModified}' --output text
```